# How to match strings containing Key Names via RegExp in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to load alphanumeric keystrokes from a text file and replaying them via AHK. Embedded in the text file are Key Names e.g. {up}.

For any alphanumeric line, I want to send an {enter}. But for embedded Key Names, I want to skip the {enter}.

Here's the Macro.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Hello World
{up}{up}
```

To detect the {up}{up} key names, I tried using RegExpMatch

```
    iskey := RegExMatch(%a_loopReadLine%, "giA)(\{\w+\})")
```

But when AHK get's to the {up}{up} content, it throws an error:

> Error: The following variable name contains an illegal character: "{up}{up}"

I've tried `IfInStr` as well. But I'm stuck at embedding key names in strings somehow.

'''

```
^r::
loop, read, Macro.txt
{
    SendInput, %a_loopReadLine% 

    iskey := RegExMatch(%a_loopReadLine%, "giA)(\{\w+\})")
    IfNotEqual, iskey, 0
    {
      SendInput, {enter}
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: change `RegExMatch(%a_loopReadLine%, "giA)(\{\w+\})")`  to `RegExMatch(a_loopReadLine, "giA)(\{\w+\})")`.  Without the %%.

Comment: functions such as regexMatch expect a variable, so do not need to be referenced with the percents. in AHK that means that you want to refer to the name of a variable within another variable, hence the error since "{" is not a legal variable character.